# How do I add blanks for skipped elements in an xml for XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am using XmlReader to read through an xml file. I do not have control over the xml file and sometimes the xml file skips elements as shown below.

```
<Part xsi:type="Part1">
  <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  <Drawing>10</Drawing>
</Part>
<Part xsi:type="Part2">
  <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Part>
```

The Drawing and Weight are in the first entry (Part 1) but not in the second one (Part 2).
This xml has 1300 entries (Part's) and not all entries (Part's) have all elements as above.

My XmlReader code is below.

```
private void Select(string elem, ArrayList al)
{
 using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xml))
 {
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        if (reader.Name == elem && reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            string output = reader.ReadString();

            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }}}}}
```

How would I handle adding an element to the Arraylist when the element is not in the entry (Part) in the xml?

Update:
I modified the code to just be an output and here is the expected output:
1
10
1
" "

I would like the output of Part 2 to display strings with a space `" "` for missing elements like Drawing.

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlReader? LINQ to XML would be considerably simpler...

Comment: I don't have to, I've never used LINQ to XML and that was the main reason for XmlReader. I would gladly use LINQ to XML if it allowed me to add skipped elements to the ArrayList.

Comment: I think we are all confused with what you are trying to accomplish here.  Can you show us your desired output?    I think there is probably a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please also show us what is "creating your output"

Comment: And why are you using `ArrayList`? It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try a syntax vwery close to this example:

[Reading XML through LINQ](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/02/11/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-94-reading-xml-through-linq-with-silverlight.aspx)

you can test existence of a node with something like this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

foreach (XElement item in document.Descendants("Part"))
{
    if (item.Element("Quantity") == null)
         al.add(string.Empty);
    else
         al.add(item.Element("Quantity").value);


}
```

Comment: It sounds like he wants to search through an array of Parts for an element name, and for each part append the value, or some default value to his array list.

Comment: I had a little trouble with my namespaces but got it working based on your code. Thank you very much.